# Why does GORM/Hibernate convert string parameter to TRUE?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.2.3

I'm trying to do a Like product search

Domain object maps to a legacy JDE table and is:

```
class JdeProduct {
    String itemNum
    String searchText
    String description
    String transUnitOfMeasure
    String priceUnitOfMeasure
    String saleableProd

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp false
        table name: 'F4101', schema: 'PRODDTA'
        version false
        id column: 'IMITM', generator: 'assigned'
        itemNum column: 'IMLITM', sqlType: 'char', length: 25
        searchText column: 'IMSRTX', sqlType: 'char', length: 30
        description column: 'IMDSC1', sqlType: 'char', length: 30
        transUnitOfMeasure column: 'IMUOM1', sqlType: 'char', length: 2
        priceUnitOfMeasure column: 'IMUOM3', sqlType: 'char', length: 2
        saleableProd column: 'IMSHCN', sqlType: 'char', length: 3
    }
}
```

My controller has this method to query the database:

```
def searchJde = {
    String likeExpression = '%' + params.searchTerm + '%'
    log.debug("Search for products like ${likeExpression}")
    def products = JdeProduct.findAllItemNumLike(likeExpression)
    log.debug("Products found: ${products.size()}");
    render products as JSON
}
```

Given a value for searchTerm of 'SL' no results are returned even though doing the like query directly in Oracle does return results.

Log output from Grails includes:

```
2014-01-21 09:30:16,294 [http-bio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG controller.ProductController - Search for products like %SL%
2014-01-21 09:30:16,356 [http-bio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG hibernate.SQL - select this_.IMITM as IMITM0_0_, this_.IMDSC1 as IMDSC2_0_0_, this_.IMLITM as IMLITM0_0_, this_.IMUOM3 as IMUOM4_0_0_, this_.IMSHCN as IMSHCN0_0_, this_.IMSRTX as IMSRTX0_0_, this_.IMUOM1 as IMUOM7_0_0_ from PRODDTA.F4101 this_ where this_.IMLITM like ?
Hibernate: select this_.IMITM as IMITM0_0_, this_.IMDSC1 as IMDSC2_0_0_, this_.IMLITM as IMLITM0_0_, this_.IMUOM3 as IMUOM4_0_0_, this_.IMSHCN as IMSHCN0_0_, this_.IMSRTX as IMSRTX0_0_, this_.IMUOM1 as IMUOM7_0_0_ from PRODDTA.F4101 this_ where this_.IMLITM like ?
2014-01-21 09:30:16,356 [http-bio-9080-exec-1] TRACE sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - true
2014-01-21 09:30:16,731 [http-bio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG controller.ProductController - Products found: 0
```

The problem seems to be related to:

```
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - true
```

I would expect this to say:

```
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - %SL%
```

Why is it binding true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was 'By' missing from the findAll. Should be findAllByItemNumLike instead of findAllItemNumLike